# Textarea suggestion giver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

Are there any bootstrap or jQuery tools that give me suggestions when I type something in a textarea? like autocomplete but I don't want to replace the whole text when I click on the suggestion. I want something like SQL editor when I start typing a table name, tables name starting with that particular letter should suggestest me. When I click on a suggestion, particular suggestion should append with the existing sentences.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://autocomplete-js.com/

Pretty much my go to autocomplete library i use in the frontend. It has no dependencies, which is awesome.

If you're more into jQuery, here's one from [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: jQuery autocomplete working like other autocomplete, I want something like in facebook, when you type your friend's name it will give suggestion and when click on the suggestion it **appends** with existing sentences you typed.